# Why does cin.getline() not work (C++)?

Tags: c++, input, output, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char text[200];
int input;


cin>>input;
if (input == 1)
{
    cin.getline(text, 200);
    cout<<text<<"\n";

}
else if(input == 0)
{
    cout <<"You entered a 0";
}

return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make a small program where the user gives an input either a 1 or 0. if the user enters a 1 then he can enter a whole sentence and stores it in the char array of text. My problem is that when I put the cin.getline() inside an if statement it no longer works. why is that?

Thanks

Comment: You have to read the remaining newline character from the first input operation  before calling `getline()`.

Comment: You have to flush the input before reading the new one

Answer (score 2):

It is not that `cin.getline()` doesn't work. It does exactly what has been asked of it: Read the line of text up to the next newline. It just so happens that `cin >> input;` has read some digits and then left the first non-digit input in the input buffer - which typically is a newline unless you typed something that wasn't a number.

You can work around this by calling `cin.ignore()`, which will "read everything up to the next newline and throw it away".

Ideally, you should decide whether you want to use `cin >>` or `cin.getline()`, and use one or the other, but that means then reading a string of text and in your code converting to a digit, and if you are a novice, that's probably a bit more complex than you actually want to make it.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now!